# Input Control Parameters not passing in Jaspersoft Reference Hyperlink to Dashboard

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports, dashboard, jasperserver

I have a jaspersoft report (line chart built in studio), and I want the data series in the chart to be hyperlinks that drilldown to open a dashboard.

Based on this [wiki page](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-do-i-drill-through-dashboard) I was able to create Reference hyperlinks so that clicking on any data series in the chart opens the correct dashboard. But I cannot get the Input Control parameters to pass correctly.

1. The **URL when I load my dashboard directly** from the repository (not by clicking hyperlinks in my line chart report) is

http://ddevrpt:8080/jasperserver-pro/dashboard/viewer.html#%2Fpublic%2FP2%2FMidcap%2FFinancial%2FDashboards%2FWell_Profile

2. The URL generated when i **do not include input controls** in my hyperlink reference expression is the same:

http://ddevrpt:8080/jasperserver-pro/dashboard/viewer.html#%2Fpublic%2FP2%2FMidcap%2FFinancial%2FDashboards%2FWell_Profile

JRXML:

```
    <itemHyperlink hyperlinkType="Reference">
            <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["./dashboard/viewer.html#%2Fpublic%2FP2%2FMidcap%2FFinancial%2FDashboards%2FWell_Profile"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
    </itemHyperlink>
```

3. The URL generated when i **do include Input Control parameter values** is different, but still loads the dashboard empty (without passing the parameter values):

http://ddevrpt:8080/jasperserver-pro/dashboard/viewer.html?hidden_WellConcatenated_0=49005478.1:%20DILTS%2044-15%20TH&hidden_OccurrenceDate_1=2015-09-28%2000:00:00.0&hidden_OccurrenceDate_2=2015-10-05%2000:00:00.0#%2Fpublic%2FP2%2FMidcap%2FFinancial%2FDashboards%2FWell_Profile

JRXML:

```
    <itemHyperlink hyperlinkType="Reference">
            <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["./dashboard/viewer.html#%2Fpublic%2FP2%2FMidcap%2FFinancial%2FDashboards%2FWell_Profile"+"&hidden_WellConcatenated_0=" + $V{WellConcatenated_0} + "&hidden_OccurrenceDate_1=" + $P{RecordDate_0_1} + "&hidden_OccurrenceDate_2=" + $P{TimeStampMinusOneWeek}]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
    </itemHyperlink>
```

4. I know I am naming the input controls correctly because if i change my link type to report execution and link to a simple report using those input controls the proper report opens and the input control values are passed correctly.

I would also appreciate if anyone has other references they can point me to for drilling down TO a dashboard from a report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working with 6.3 and was able to resolve the issue with a small modification to the HyperlinkReferenceExpression syntax.

Specifically, I removed the "_hidden" before the input control resource IDs:

**HyperlinkReferenceExpression:**

**original syntax:**

> "./dashboard/viewer.html#%2Fpublic%2FP2%2FMidcap%2FFinancial%2FDashboards%2FWell_Profile"
>
> +"&hidden_WellConcatenated_0=" + $V{WellConcatenated_0}
>
> +"&hidden_OccurrenceDate_1=" + $P{RecordDate_0_1}
>
> +"&hidden_OccurrenceDate_2=" + $P{TimeStampMinusOneWeek}

**modified syntax:**

> "./dashboard/viewer.html#%2Fpublic%2FP2%2FMidcap%2FFinancial%2FDashboards%2FWell_Profile"
>
> +"&WellConcatenated_0=" + $V{WellConcatenated_0}
>
> +"&OccurrenceDate_1=" +$P{RecordDate_0_1}
>
> +"&OccurrenceDate_2=" +  $P{TimeStampMinusOneWeek}

Comment: Thanks for the update! I had actually thought about removing that "hidden_" prefix but for some reason I assumed you would have tried it already. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're running 6.4.0. I'm not sure that approach is still valid.

You will likely need to register a *custom hyperlink handler* in your report in order to drill-down to a Dashboard. See here for more details: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-use-custom-hyperlink-handler-dashboard-jasperreports-server

And here: http://www.helicaltech.com/use-custom-hyperlink-handler-with-a-dashboard-in-jasperreports-server/

Let me know if that works for you on 6.4.0!

Comment: Thank you for these resources. I am waiting to hear from IT regarding the location of our server deployment folders but really appreciate the references.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bad solution., but it worked for me.

In my Dataset - query I used the following:

```
Select p.printer_name, p.display_name, $P{start_date_1} as start_date_param, ....
```

Then, use the `start_date_param` as a field in the hyperlink.